# Unable to pass parameter to React Button callback function on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a material-ui button and am trying to pass some parameter to my callback function on click.

For some reason, the below way is not working.

```
const myApi = async (param) => {
}

<Button onClick={myApi('text')}
    data-testid='my-field'>
    <Icon accessibleText="__label__search" name="search" size={12} />
</Button>
```

Comment: There's no need to add "please help" to your questions (currently you have 198 of them). Technical writing is an expectation here, and adding excessive and flowery politenesses won't get you help any faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
onClick = {() => myApi("text")}
```